# Divergence of a reciprocal

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Question: Say that  $\sum a_n$ converges and $a_n$ does not equal 0 for all natural numbers.

Prove: $\sum 1/a_n$ diverges.

My understanding:
I see that $1/a_n$ is the reciprocal of $a_n$. I have done many examples with numbers that prove this theorem, but I am not sure how to really prove this without testing numbers with convergence/divergence tests.
Would I use the comparison theorem test here?

Comment: $\lim a_n = ?$ And knowing this, $\lim \frac{1}{an} = ?$

Comment: Related: [Convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ given convergence of $\sum a_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54293).

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If the series $\sum a_n $ converges, then the general term $a_n $ must go to zero when $n\to+\infty $.

What about $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac {1}{a_n} $$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\text{ converges}&\Longrightarrow\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n=0\\&\Longrightarrow\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac1{|a_n|}=+\infty\\&\Longrightarrow\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{a_n}\text{ diverges.}\end{align*}